# login page - create a basic form with an input field and a button

Tags: visualforce, form

I need to check if `Customer__c` (my object exists or not) by entering the `Customer__c.username` to a an input-field in the form and then by clicking on a button is should reference me to other page if i got this username in my table of customers.
How can I do it? Do I have access to my `Customer__c` table of all Customers in Salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="loginController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputPanel id="getInput" rendered="{!getInput}">
            <apex:inputText value="{!userName}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchUserName}" reRender="showResult"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!!getInput}">
            <apex:outputText value="Congrats. That username is available in database. You can login using that." rendered="{!IF(customerObjList != NULL && customerObjList.size() > 0,true,false)}"
            <apex:outputText value="Sorry. That username is unavailable in database. You can signup with that username to use it." rendered="{!IF(customerObjList != NULL && customerObjList.size() > 0,false,true)}"
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Controller class:**

```
public with sharing class loginController {
    public String userName {get; set;}
    public List<Customer__c> customerObjList {get; set;}
    public loginController() {
        getInput = True;
        customerObjList = new List<Customer__c>();
    }
    public void searchUserName() {
        getInput = False;
        customerObjList = [SELECT Id, UserName__c FROM Customer__c WHERE UserName__c =: userName];
    }
}
```

**Assumptions:**

1. Customer__c is the API Name of the Object.
2. User_Name__c is the API Name of the Field you are searching for in Customer__c object.

Comment: got an FIELD INTEGRITY EXCEPTION.. why?

Comment: You should use the actual field and object api. The one i used is based on assumptions

Answer (score 0):

**Apex Class**

```
public with sharing class loginController {
    public String userName {get; set;}
    public String password {get; set;}
    public Boolean getInput {get;set;}
     public Boolean ischeck {get;set;}
    public List ObjList {get; set;}
    public loginController() {
       getInput = True;
        ObjList = new List();
    }
    public void searchUserName() {
       getInput = False;
        ObjList = [SELECT Id, Email__c,Password__c FROM External_User__c  WHERE Email__c =: userName Limit 1];
        if(!ObjList.isEmpty()){
            ischeck = true;

        }else{
            ischeck = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**VF Page**

```
 <apex:page standardstylesheets="false" showheader="false" sidebar="false" controller="loginController">
<apex:form>
    <apex:outputPanel id="getInput" rendered="{!getInput}">
    <apex:inputText styleClass="form-control" value="{!userName}"/>
    <apex:inputText styleClass="form-control" value="{!password}" />
    <apex:commandButton value="Login"  styleClass="btn btn-success btn-sm" action="{!searchUserName}" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!!getInput}">
    <apex:outputText>{!ischeck}</apex:outputText>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
```